# How can I specify that a type is an instance of a given class type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to make a `Constructor` type that takes a class as a type parameter and returns the signature of its constructor.

This would be useful in defining a static property `make` method on a class that can create an instance of that class rather than creating it with a `new ClassInstance(...)` statement.

This is what I've got so far:

```js
type ClassConstructorArgs<T> = T extends { new (...args: infer A): any }
  ? A
  : never;

type Constructor<T> = (...args: ClassConstructorArgs<T>) => T;

class Person {
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}

  static make: Constructor<typeof Person> = (...args) => new Person(...args);
  //                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // Type 'Person' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof Person': prototype, make
}
```

The problem is that the static `make` has an error: `Type 'Person' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof Person': prototype, make`

I understand that this is because my `Constructor` type is wrong, constructors of class `T` don't return the class `T` itself but an instance of `T`.

But then I don't know how I can express that `Constructor` returns an instance of `T` rather than the class `T` itself. Is that even possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

Typescript has builtin utilities both for [ConstructorParameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterst) and [InstanceType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet):

```
type Constructor<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = 
  (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => InstanceType<T>;

class Person {
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}

  static make: Constructor<typeof Person> = (...args) => new Person(...args);
}

const p = Person.make('some name', 1); // p is of type Person
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqUEAHsBAgCZJQIQDuUAFAHRsCGqA5kgFxTsEIAJRQAvAD4BQqWOZsWnHv3jI0WHKgAKndgFsI5VEkITRkqAEk1gzBALgIpgNwBYAFAfMAG3ZIaWhDGiFAA3h5QUJiIKBjYuExg6ABG3gCWmLT6EPyxaQhcADRQSakZAlw5tOh6yUGioVAAvh4RUCjswOV67ADWVaqxGrh4oJBwAGZQgcEIsvIc3EjmUnSMM0iIrIs8wm7uLZ7u0Wol4tNBmwgsPf1MAOSbBlkG98UAjHtQAPTfZ2k0SZQMbQDaIIA)

---

If you wonder how these utilities are defined and what's wrong with your attempt, here you go:

```
type ConstructorParameters<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = 
  T extends new (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;

type InstanceType<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = 
  T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts)

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea! Clever how the `InstanceType` is defined. Do you know why in both types the type constraints are duplicated in the parameter declaration and inside the type body? It seems redundant

Comment: I don't know why it is duplicated, but one could define something like `type Newable = new (...args: any) => any;` and reuse it